# Advantage to assigning a Word Interop call to a variable if it isn't used

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

Say I've got a call like this

```
Document document = application.Documents.Open(...)
```

I can then refer to document and do stuff to it much like I can with any other variable. For example,

```
int count = document.Words.Count;
```

However, if I don't want to do anything with the result is there any advantage to assigning it to a variable? I.e. is this

```
Document document = application.Documents.Open(...)
```

Any better than

```
application.Documents.Open(...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main benefit of assigning it to a variable is so that you can call `ReleaseComObject` on it. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3198193/34092 .

Also see https://ausdotnet.wordpress.com/category/technical/com-interop/ .